# jScrollPane and relative width?

Tags: javascript, css, jscrollpane

i am experimenting with jScrollPane (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html) which is a wonderfull piece of art. 
No I have the problem, that the div I want to scroll with jScrollPane has a absolute position and dynamic width an height:

```
.scroll-pane
{
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: left; 
  background: rgba(40,40,40,0.5); 
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 100px;
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 70%;
  min-height: 40%;
  text-transform: none;
  bottom: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

If i now change the windows-size, the jScrollPane breaks. If i reload the page in the new size, the scrollbar works again perfectly.

Is there a way to trigger a reinitialization of jScrollPane if the windows-size is changing?

It would be nice if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
  });
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much! With this little piece of code it works how i want it to :)